# Is there a difference between a function with and without a return statement?

Tags: javascript

Say you have 2 identical functions that do not return a value

```
function a() {
    // do some interesting things
}

function b() {
    // do the same interesting things
    return;
}
```

Function `b` is obviously more verbose but is there any functional difference between these?

Comment: A good answer to this should include a link to the relevant part of the ECMA spec.

Comment: return; basically means terminate function here. So if you have it as the last bit of your function it does not do anything useful.

Comment: 12.9 in the spec, for those interested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no real difference; both will return `undefined`.

Functions with no return statement will return `undefined`, as will functions with an empty `return` statement.

---

To confirm this for yourself, you can run this code -- [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AhbFG/):

```
​function a() {
}

function b() {
    return;
}

var aResult = a();
var bResult = b();

alert(aResult === bResult);  //alerts true
```

Answer (score 3):

Adam is correct; both functions return undefined, and either way is absolutely fine if you don't care about the return value (or desire the value to be undefined).  However, it's often better in more complex programs to explicitly return from a function, especially since Javascript programs often have complex callback mechanisms.  For example, in this piece of code (just a little more complex than yours) I believe the return statement really helps clarify the code:

```
function someAsyncFunction(someVar, callback) {
    // do something, and then...
    callback(someVar);
    // will return undefined
    return;
}

function c(){
    var someState = null;
    if (some condition) {
        return someAsyncFunction(some variable, function () {
            return "from the callback but not the function";
        });
        // we've passed the thread of execution to someAsyncFunction
        // and explicitly returned from function c.  If this line
        // contained code, it would not be executed.
    } else if (some other condition) {
         someState = "some other condition satisfied";
    } else {
         someState = "no condition satisfied";
    }
    // Note that if you didn't return explicitly after calling
    // someAsyncFunction you would end up calling doSomethingWith(null)
    // here.  There are obviously ways you could avoid this problem by
    // structuring your code differently, but explicit returns really help
    // avoid silly mistakes like this which can creep into complex programs.
    doSomethingWith(someState);
    return;
}

// Note that we don't care about the return value.
c();
```

Comment: Totally subjective, but I totally disagree. I don't think it makes the code any easier to read. On the contrary, it's unnecessary so it only serves to clutter. My 2c. I suppose each to his own.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you are returning a value. So for instance,

```
function b() {
  return 'hello';
}

a = b();

console.log(a);
```

Will output "hello" to your console.