# Are there differences between an empty function and a function that only returns nothing?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference between a function with and without a return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435703/is-there-a-difference-between-a-function-with-and-without-a-return-statement)

Are there differences between an empty function and a function that only returns nothing?

Empty function:

```
function a() {
}
```

Function that only returns nothing:

```
function b() {
    return;
}
```

Comment: @user1689607 Thanks. I tried to search for "empty function".

Comment: I searched before answering too, but did not find this one. Instead I had found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596404/return-false-the-same-as-return) which isn't the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the `return` is implied if omitted in the first one. Both of them return `undefined`.

```
// In the console:
a();
// undefined
b();
// undefined
```

To expand a little further, this isn't the same as returning `null`:

```
function c() {
    return null;
}

c();
// null (which is a value, albeit a null one)

// Because
a() === c();
// false
null === undefined;
// false
```

Comment: The `typeof` result has no bearing on this. `undefined` is as much of a value as `null`, and `null` is not an object even though `typeof` tells us it is.